# Smoothing Service Area Polygons

Tags: polygon, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, network-analyst, service-area, isochrone

I've a created a web service using the ArcGIS API for Javascript that displays isochrones (service area polygons) generated from a network dataset built in ESRI's network analyst.

My issue is that the polygons are very jagged and I'd like to smooth them.  Typically, I accomplish this in the polygon generation tab of the service area properties in ArcMap (trim, generalized, detailed).

However, this seems to have no effect after publishing the dataset as a service.  I've been able to alter the polygons by adjusting the Default Output Geometry Precision both in the Service Editor and in the Javascript, but this alone is not enough.

Are there other options either in Javascript or in the publishing process for smoothing polygons that I've missed?

Answer (score 2):

> My issue is that the polygons are very jagged and I'd like to generalize them

generalizing is a technique to remove vertices from an original geometry so its *expected* that specifying an increasingly large value for `outputGeometryPrecision` would result in more jagged output.  this is because generalization is different than smoothing.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-simplifying-and-smoothing-a-feature.htm

i don't think it'd be helpful in this scenario, but in general both 3.x and 4.x of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript include a client-side geometry engine for manipulating individual vector features and [`generalize()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-geometryEngine.html#generalize) is available there too.